# Javascript uploading file alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

In the above image the delete button need to align properly. in my code it get align based on file name length.

```
 <script>
        var filelist = new Array();

        updateList = function () {
            var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
            var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');

            var HTML = "<table>";
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
                filelist[i]=input.files.item(i).name;
                HTML += "<tr><td>" + filelist[i] + "</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button ></button></td></tr>";
            }
            HTML += "</table>";
            output.innerHTML += HTML;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use CSS to make all the `table` elements the same width. Or put all the `tr` elements in the same table. That way you won't even need the CSS.

Comment: Its not best practice to use `&nbsp;`. try using css or two column row.

Comment: Even though I don't recommend using `<table>` elements for layout, all you need is to insert all the files into the same `<table>` element instead of creating a new `<table>` element for each row.

Comment: table {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0 3px;
            table-layout: fixed
        }
        tr:nth-child(1n) {
            border: 2px solid;
            background-color: #eceff1;
            color: Black;
        }
        tr:nth-child(2n) {
            border: 2px solid;
            color: Black;
        }
        td {
            padding-top: .5em;
            padding-left:.5em;
            padding-right:.5em;
            padding-bottom: .5em;
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this.

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 3px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
table
{
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 300px;
}

td
{
  border: 1px solid green;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

[try jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7nfU/)

Comment: i would like to place the delete button right side corner and the file name in the left side corner

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0 2px;
        width: 600px;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    tr:nth-child(1n) {
        border: 2px solid;
        background-color: #eceff1;
        color: Black;
    }
    tr:nth-child(2n) {
        border: 2px solid;
        color: Black;
    }
    td {           
        padding-top: .5em;
        padding-left: .5em;
        padding-right: .5em;
        padding-bottom: .5em;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
        display: none;
    }
    .label1 {
        padding: 3px;
        background: #fff;
        display: table;
        color:black;
    }
    button {
        background-image: url('../../Images/delete.ico');
        background-size: cover;
        padding-right:0px;
        background-color: Transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: none;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
</style>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', "button", function (e) {
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });
 });
</script>
<script>
    var filelist = new Array();
    updateList = function () {
        var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
        var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');
        var HTML = "<table>";
        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
            filelist[i]=input.files.item(i).name;
            HTML += "<tr><td>" + filelist[i] + "</td><td><button ></button></td></tr>";
        }
        HTML += "</table>";
        output.innerHTML += HTML;
    }
</script>
```

In the above script the delete button is showing in fixed order but i want the file name to be aligned at left and delete button need to at right side corner.

[image]